# How to divide bit stream into packet

Tags: matlab

I have a problem that need your help. I have a bit stream

```
S=[1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0] %it is a vector
```

Now I want to group 3bits of S into a packet. So my packets are that

```
packet 1: 100
packet 2: 110
packet 3: 111
packet 4: 110
```

How to implement it by matlab code
This is my code. But it does work as my scheme

```
packetsize=3;
k=12 %number of bit stream
%S = rand(1,12)<0.5 % create random message vector
S=[1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0] %it is a vector
for i=1:k
        packet=s(packetsize*(i-1)+1:(i*packetsize))
end
```

Comment: You probably want `reshape`, but fyi you can make the for loop go in increments of 3 like this: `for i=1:3:k`

Comment: Your function reshape(S,[],3) is better. But how to access each row as packet. I try to A=reshape(S,[],3) , packet1=A(1,:); But it return as vector

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you just want `reshape(S,[],3)`?

Comment: Good function sir. But output is packet1=[1 0 0]...But I want packet1 is number as 100. Do you need more function

Comment: Are you sure you want the number as 100? What do you plan to do with it. With my function you can access the ith packet as `packet(i,:)`

Comment: Because my research is channel coding. It only apply for bit level. Example 1 xor 0=1, but now I want to apply for packet level as 100 xor 001 = 101...Is my way correct?

Comment: You can use a vector for that though no problem (rather than the decimal number 100)

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
>> S = [1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0];
>> packets = reshape(S, 3, []).' * [100;10;1]
packets =
   100
   110
   111
   110
```

Now you can access the i-th "packet" as: `packets(i,:)`